# Decrypt data with AES-128 key and salt in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, aes, phpseclib

I am new for AES encryption methodology and try to implement encrypt data at the client end and decrypt data at the server end.

What I have done so far is, I have implemented client portal in java and server scripts in PHP. I define AES-key, salt and I encrypt data in the client end(In-JAVA) with the help of AES-key and salt. Now, I am calling an API with parameter key, salt and data to the server(php script) and try to decrypt the data. 
I am using `phpseclib` lib for decrypt the data.

I have sample `decrypt` function as below. (Note:- I already decode with base64_decode this key, salt and data before sending to this function)

```
public function decryptAES($data,$key,$salt){
     $cipher = new Crypt_AES(CRYPT_MODE_CBC);
     $ivsize = strlen($salt);
     $cipher->setIV($salt);
     $cipher->setKey($key);
     $decrypt = $cipher->decrypt($data);
     echo($decrypt);
     return $decrypt;
}
```

I am getting `decrypt` message as null. I take a look into the lib and gone through some classes which named as "Base.php" and try to debug out when it actual decrypting data. I dump plaintext and got an output as below.

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
    <small>G:\Installer\wamp64\www\userRegistration\lib\phpseclib\Crypt\Base.php:1081:</small>
    <small>string</small>
    <font color='#cc0000'>'Zx�Q���&#39;m�ԉ��^�ܶB�eKs�&gt;�`&#0;�_����c^��m������h�~Ut�&#39;�'</font>
    <i>(length=64)</i>
</pre>
```

can anyone help me in this? or is this way correct to do or any methodology i missed here?

Comment: You have missed that for XML you will have to use base 64 encoding for binary. If you just use binary then you will lose data (and because you cannot decrypt anymore, for encryption, you will lose *all* data). Note that CBC mode for transport security is completely insecure, even for keeping data confidential (padding oracles).

Comment: In addition to what Maarten Bodewes noted keep in mind that phpseclib assumes PKCS8 padding has been done. If you want to disable that requirement do `$cipher->disablePadding()`. If that's done then the ciphertext will *absolutely* need to be a multiple of the block size (with CBC) but if it is then phpseclib won't return false under any circumstance. The only way phpseclib can return false when padding is enabled is if the last byte of the decrypted ciphertext isn't a number between 1 and the block size (16), due to the way PKCS1 padding works.

Comment: @neubert That should be PKCS#7 padding. PKCS#7 specifies the Cryptographic Message Syntax and it includes this type of padding. PKCS#8 is a format for encrypting private keys, it references PKCS#5 which defines PKCS#7 compatible padding, but only for 8 byte block ciphers.